# how do i convert ['121341']['132324'] (type string) into 2 separate lists python

Tags: python

i am trying to add some file operation capabilities to a example program, i am strugling with the reading from the file. here is the code that is modified.

```
def read(fn): 
    fileout=open(f"{fn}","a+")
    fileout.seek(0,0)
    s=fileout.readlines()
    if s==[]:
        print("the file specified does not appear to exists or is empty. if the file does not exist, it will be created")
    else:
        last=s[-1]
        print(last)
        print(type(last))
        convert(last)

def find(last):
    tup=last.partition(".")
    fi=tup[0:1]
    return fi[0]
def convert(last):
    tup=last.partition(".")
    part=tup[2:]
    print(part)
    part=part[0]
    print(part)
    part=part.split("\n")
    print(part)
    part=part[0]
    print(part)
    print(type(part))
#__main__
file(fn)
```

the write functionality writes in the form of
(fileindex number).[(planned campaign)][(conducted campaign)]
example:- some random data writen to the file by the program(first two number are dates)

```
0.['12hell']['12hh']
1.['12hell']['12hh']
2.['121341']['132324']
```

but i am strugling to write the read function, i don't understand how i could convert the data back.

with the current read function i get back

```
['121341']['132324']
```

as a string type, i have brainstormed many ideas but could not figureout how to convert string to list(they need to be 2 separate lists)

edit: the flaw as actually in the format that i was writing in, i added a , between the two lists and used eval as suggested in an answer, thanks

Comment: There is too much code here that doesn't relate to your question. Please reduce the code to only focus on your problem. So, give the file contents (which you do, although you speak of dates, but example data has no dates... so make it concrete), and **only** the code that needs to read that file, and what the expected result should be of that reading. Nothing else. No 3 display functions, no menu, no .... any of the other stuff that does not relate to the question.

Comment: i have removed the unnessary code as you asked, i just can't figure out how to convert the string into 2 separate lists. i plan to use the convert function to convert the string back to lists, still can't figure it out how

Comment: I need to insist. There is still code that displays a menu and asks for input. All that doesn't relate to your question. Please simplify to only focus on the problem.

Comment: removed the write function too, it was not related to the question, thanks for the advice, still new to the community

Comment: To the question itself: is this format the *required* format? Can't you write to your file in some standard format, like JSON? That would greatly simplify the reading process.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to use `json` module (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for working with data in files. It will save you a lot of work in a long run. For starter it will automatically convert the data you load from string to dictionary/list/whatever it was originally. To access deeply nested structures, use `input()` repeatedly. Like: `first_index = int(input())`, `second_index = int(input())` and then use that to access the nested data item, idk: `my_data[first_index][second_index]`

Comment: People downvote and go on. They don't wait for you to update your question. It is therefore very important to phrase a question in the best way possible from the very start. That's life on Stack Overflow. It should be very *focused*, *clear*, *show effort*, include input examples, and *expected* results for them,... Ideally, the reader should be able to copy your code in their IDE, run it, and reproduce the problem without having to do anything else.

Comment: A well prepared asker will not get into this situation. Did you read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the hints you got during the editing of your question, and follow *all* of the guidelines *before* you posted?

Comment: @trincot this is the second or third time of me ever asking any question here, and no i have not read that, will read it right away

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insert a `','` inbetween the brackets, then use eval. This will return a tuple of lists.

```
strLists = "['121341']['132324']['abcdf']"
strLists = strLists.replace('][', '],[')

evalLists = eval(strLists)


for each in evalLists:
    print(each)
```

**Output:**

```
['121341']
['132324']
['abcdf']
```

Comment: so is there no way i could convert it to list with the current format of data? @chitown88